# Swift - Remove key and values from dictionary [String : Any]

Tags: swift, string, dictionary, any

I am trying to removed block users from a dictionary [String : Any] that I am grabbing from the database. At first I grab the list of UID's that the current user has blocked:

```
var updatedBlockList: Any?
func findBlockUsers() {
    // find current users list of blocked users
    guard let currentUserUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    let blockedUsers = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(currentUserUid)

    blockedUsers.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let userIdsDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
        userIdsDictionary.forEach({ (key, value) in
            guard let userDictionary = value as? [String: Any] else { return }

            var blockedList : Any
            blockedList = userDictionary.keys

            print(blockedList)

            self.updateBlockList(blockedList: blockedList)

        })
    })
}

func updateBlockList(blockedList: Any) {
    updatedBlockList = blockedList
    print(updatedBlockList)
}
```

If I print updatedBlockList I get: ["gdqzOXPWaiaTn93YMJBEv51UUUn1", "RPwVj59w8pRFLf55VZ6LGX6G2ek2", "xmigo8CPzhNLlXN4oTHMpGo7f213"]

I now want to take those UID's (which will be the key in UserIdsDictionary and remove them after I pull ALL the users:

```
fileprivate func fetchAllUserIds() {

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users")
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let userIdsDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

        userIdsDictionary.forEach({ (key, value) in

            // attempting to remove the blocked users here without any luck
            var updatedKey = key as String?
            updatedKey?.remove(at: self.updatedBlockList as! String.Index)
            print(updatedKey!)

            guard let  userDictionary = value as? [String: Any] else { return }

            let user = User(uid: key, dictionary: userDictionary)
            self.fetchPostsWithUser(user: user)
        })

    }) { (err) in
        print("Failed to fetch following user ids:", err)
    }

}
```

I get this error when trying to remove: Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Dictionary.Keys' (0x1de2f6b78) to 'Swift.String.Index'

I'm sure i'm going about this the wrong way, but I know i'm close. The end goal is to take the blocked users UID's and remove them from the dictionary. Any help would be very much appreciated!!

Comment: Looks like `self.updatedBlockList as! String.Index` is the offending line. I don't see how `self.updatedBlockList` could be an `Index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your forEach loop on `userIdsDictionary` is the wrong approach here so rather than trying to fix that code I would use a different approach and loop over the `updatedBlockList`

```
for item in updatedBlockList {
    if let userID = item as? String {
        userIdsDictionary.removeValue(forKey: userID)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, here is the final changes that were made to make it work.

```
var updatedBlockList = [String]()

func findBlockUsers() {
    // find current users list of blocked users
    guard let currentUserUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    let blockedUsers = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(currentUserUid)

    blockedUsers.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let userIdsDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
        userIdsDictionary.forEach({ (key, value) in
            guard let userDictionary = value as? [String: Any] else { return }

            let blockedList = Array(userDictionary.keys)

            print(blockedList)

            self.updateBlockList(blockedList: blockedList)

        })
    })
}

func updateBlockList(blockedList: [String]) {
    updatedBlockList = blockedList
    print(updatedBlockList)
}

fileprivate func fetchAllUserIds() {

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users")
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [weak self] (snapshot) in
        guard var userIdsDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any], let self = self else { return }

        for item in self.updatedBlockList {
            userIdsDictionary.removeValue(forKey: item)
        }

        userIdsDictionary.forEach({ (key, value) in

            guard let  userDictionary = value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            let user = User(uid: key, dictionary: userDictionary)
            self.fetchPostsWithUser(user: user)
        })
    }) { (err) in
        print("Failed to fetch following user ids:", err)
    }

}
```